# Moving Details box renders Add to Cart Button inoperable - Magento

Tags: html, magento, layout

My site offers products that have multiple options. Some with as many as 5-8 options. So, the "details box" ends up way beneath all of the options. Also, the details are to long to place into the "short description" box at the top. So, I moved the details box above the options box. When doing this it causes the "add to cart" button to no longer work. I have tried moving code all over the page & no matter which portion of code I move the "add to cart button" won't work. (I have tried moving the options code & the details box code) I am using a custom theme called BuyShop. Here is a link to one of the products so you can see what I am talking about & trying to do: http://www.dvineinspiration.com/featured-products/mime-basic-plus.html. I have also included the code from the product/view.phtml file below.

```
<!--PRODUCT BOX-->
<?php
    $widthSmall=62;
    $heightSmall=62;
    $widthMedium=460;
    $heightMedium=440;
    $_video = $this->getProduct()->getVideobox();
    $_customtab = $this->getProduct()->getCustomtab();
    $_customtabtitle = $this->getProduct()->getCustomtabtitle();
    $image_size=Mage::getStoreConfig('buyshoplayout/product_info/product_info_image_size');
    $main_image_popup='';
    $popup_video='';
    if(Mage::helper('lightboxes')->isActive())
    {
        /*popups*/
        $helper             = Mage::helper('lightboxes');
        $rel                = $helper->getLightboxRel($helper->getConfig('lightbox_type'));
        $class              = $helper->getLightboxClass($helper->getConfig('lightbox_type'));
        $main_image_popup='class="'.$class.'" rel="'.$rel.'"';
        $popup_video='class="video '.$class.'" rel="'.$rel.'"';
    }
    switch($image_size)
    {
        case 'small':
            if(Mage::helper('buyshopconfig')->getMediaCount($_product) or !empty($_video))
            {
                $span0=4;
                $span1=1;
                $span2=3;
                $span3=8;
            }
            else
            {
                $span0=3;
                $span1=1;
                $span2=3;
                $span3=9;
            }
            $height_thumbs=206;
            break;
        case 'medium':
            if(Mage::helper('buyshopconfig')->getMediaCount($_product) or !empty($_video))
            {
                $span0=5;
                $span1=1;
                $span2=4;
                $span3=7;
            }
            else
            {
                $span0=4;
                $span1=1;
                $span2=4;
                $span3=8;
            }
            $height_thumbs=350;
            break;
        case 'big':
            if(Mage::helper('buyshopconfig')->getMediaCount($_product) or !empty($_video))
            {
                $span0=6;
                $span1=1;
                $span2=5;
                $span3=6;
            }else
            {
                $span0=5;
                $span1=1;
                $span2=5;
                $span3=7;
            }
            $height_thumbs=422;
            break;
    }
?>
<form action="<?php echo $this->getSubmitUrl($_product) ?>" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form"<?php if($_product->getOptions()): ?> enctype="multipart/form-data"<?php endif; ?>>
    <div class="product-box">
        <div class="no-display">
            <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?php echo $_product->getId() ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="related_product" id="related-products-field" value="" />
        </div>
        <div class="row">
        <div class="span<?php echo $span0?>">
            <div class="product-img-box">
                <div class="row">
                    <?php if(Mage::helper('buyshopconfig')->getMediaCount($_product) or !empty($_video)):?>
                    <div class="span<?php echo $span1?>">
                        <div class="more-views flexslider">
                            <ul  class="slides">
                                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('media') ?>
                                <?php if(!empty($_video)):?>
                                <li><a   class="video"  href="<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($this->getProduct(), $_video, 'video') ?>"><i class=" icon-link"></i></a></li>
                                <?php endif;?>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php endif;?>
                    <div class="span<?php echo $span2?>">
                        <div class="product-image">
                            <a <?php echo $main_image_popup;?> title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getImageLabel())?>" <?php if(!Mage::helper('lightboxes')->isActive()):?>class="cloud-zoom"<?php endif;?> href="<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image', $_product->getFile())?>" <?php if(!Mage::helper('lightboxes')->isActive()):?>id='zoom1' data-rel="position: 'right', adjustX: 10, adjustY: 0"<?php endif;?>>
                                <img class="product-retina" data-image2x="<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image', $_product->getFile())->resize($widthMedium*2, $heightMedium*2)?>" src="<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image', $_product->getFile())->resize($widthMedium, $heightMedium)?>" alt=""  />
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="pull-right hidden"><a href="#" class="fancybox fancy-zoom"><i class="icon-zoom-in"></i></a></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="span<?php echo $span3?>">
            <div class="product-shop">
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('custom_related_block') ?>
                <div class="product_info_left">
                    <div class="product-name">
                        <h1><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></h1>
                    </div>
                    <?php if(Mage::getStoreConfig('buyshoplayout/product_info/sku')):?>
                        <p><?php echo $this->__('SKU') ?>: <b><?php echo nl2br($_product->getSku()) ?></b></p>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php if(!Mage::getStoreConfig('buyshopconfig/options/catalog_mode')):?>
                    <div class="product_type_data_price"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_type_data') ?></div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
<div class="share-buttons share-buttons-panel" data-style="medium" data-counter="true" data-oauth="true" data-hover="true" data-promo-callout="left" data-buttons="twitter,facebook,pinterest"></div></p>
   <div class="add-to-links">
                        <ul>
                            <?php echo Mage::helper('buyshopconfig')->addWishCompLink($_product,$this,true); ?>
                            <?php if ($this->canEmailToFriend()): ?>
                            <li><a href="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/product')->getEmailToFriendUrl($_product) ?>" class="small_icon_color"><i class="icon-at"></i></a><a href="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/product')->getEmailToFriendUrl($_product) ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Email to a friend') ?></a></li>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, false, true)?>
<?php if(!Mage::getStoreConfig('buyshopconfig/options/catalog_mode')):?>
                    <?php  echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product) ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <div class="socialsplugins_wrapper">
                        <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('buyshop_social_like_buttons')->toHtml() ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php if ($_product->getShortDescription()):?>
                        <div class="short-description"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, nl2br($_product->getShortDescription()), 'short_description') ?></div>
                    <?php endif;?>
                    <?php echo Mage::helper('buyshopconfig')->countdownSpecialPrice($_product,'defaultCountdown',$this);?>
                     <?php if(!Mage::getStoreConfig('buyshopconfig/options/catalog_mode')):?>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('alert_urls') ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getTierPriceHtml() ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('extrahint') ?>
                        <?php if (!$this->hasOptions()):?>
                            <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addtocart') ?>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('extra_buttons') ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('other');?>
                          <?php if(Mage::getStoreConfig('buyshoplayout/product_info/qr')):?>
                    <div class="clearfix hidden-phone" style="margin: 20px 0 0 0">
                        <img src="http://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?size=100x100&data=<?php echo Mage::helper("core/url")->getCurrentUrl()  ?>" alt="QR:  <?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?>"/>
                    </div>
                    <?php endif;?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
<?php  $modules_enable=Mage::getStoreConfig('advanced/modules_disable_output');?>
<div class="row">
    <div class="span12">
        <ul class="nav-tabs" id="myTab">
            <li class="active"><a href="#tab1"><?php echo $this->__('Description') ?></a></li>
            <?php if(!$modules_enable['Mage_Review']):?><li><a href="#tab2"><?php echo $this->__('Reviews') ?></a></li><?php endif;?>
            <?php if(!$modules_enable['Mage_Tag']):?><li><a href="#tab3"><?php echo $this->__('Tags') ?></a></li><?php endif;?>
            <?php if ($_customtab && Mage::getStoreConfig('buyshoplayout/product_info/custom_tab')): ?>
            <li><a href="#tab4"><?php if(!empty($_customtabtitle)) echo html_entity_decode($this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($this->getProduct(), $_customtabtitle, 'customtabtitle'));else echo 'Custom tab title' ?></a></li>
            <?php endif;?>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
                <?php foreach ($this->getChildGroup('detailed_info', 'getChildHtml') as $alias => $html):?>
                <div class="box-collateral <?php echo "box-{$alias}"?>">
                    <?php if ($title = $this->getChildData($alias, 'title')):?>
                    <h2><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($title); ?></h2>
                    <?php endif;?>
                    <?php echo $html; ?>
                </div>
                <?php endforeach;?>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('reviews') ?>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="tab3">
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_additional_data') ?>
            </div>
            <?php if ($_customtab): ?>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="tab4">
                <?php echo $this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($this->getProduct(), $_customtab, 'customtab') ?>
            </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
</div></div></div>
<?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $this->hasOptions()):?>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container1', '', true, true) ?>
                    <?php endif;?>
                    <?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $this->hasOptions()):?>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container2', '', true, true) ?>
                    <?php endif;?>
    </div>
    </div>
<!--PRODUCT BOX EOF-->
</form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('upsell_products') ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    <?php
    ?>
    jQuery(function(){
        var  PreviewSliderHeight = function() {
            var big_image_height= <?php echo $height_thumbs?>;
            var preview_image_height= jQuery('div.more-views ul.slides li:first-child').height();
            var slider_height = Math.round (big_image_height/preview_image_height) * preview_image_height - 10;
            jQuery(".flexslider.more-views .flex-viewport").css({
                "min-height": slider_height + "px"
            });
            if((slider_height-(jQuery('div.more-views ul.slides li:first-child').height()*jQuery('div.more-views ul.slides li').length))>=-10)
            {
                jQuery('.more-views .flex-next').remove()
                jQuery('.more-views .flex-prev').remove()
            }
        };
        jQuery('.flexslider.more-views').flexslider({
            animation: "slide",
            autoplay: false,
            minItems: 3,
            animationLoop: false,
            direction: "vertical",
            controlNav: false,
            slideshow: false,
            prevText: "<i class='icon-down'></i>",
            nextText: "<i class='icon-up'></i>",
            start: PreviewSliderHeight
        });
    })
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    var productAddToCartForm = new VarienForm('product_addtocart_form');
    <?php if(Mage::getStoreConfig('buyshopconfig/options/ajax_add_to_cart')){?>
    productAddToCartForm.submit = function(button, url) {
        if (this.validator.validate()) {
            var form = this.form;
            var oldUrl = form.action;
            if (url) {
                form.action = url;
            }
            var e = null;
            // Start of our new ajax code
            if (!url) {
                url = jQuery('#product_addtocart_form').attr('action');
            }


            url = url.replace("checkout/cart","ajax/index"); // New Code
            var data = jQuery('#product_addtocart_form').serialize();
            data += '&isAjax=1';
            jQuery('#preloader .loader').fadeIn(300);
            try {
                jQuery.ajax( {
                    url : url,
                    dataType : 'json',
                    type : 'post',
                    data &colon; data,
                    success : function(data) {
                        jQuery('#ajax_loader').hide();
                        if(data.status == 'ERROR'){
                            jQuery('#preloader .loader').hide();
                            jQuery('#preloader .inside').html(data.message);
                            jQuery('#preloader .message').fadeIn(300);
                            setTimeout(function(){
                                jQuery('#preloader .message').fadeOut();
                            },1500);
                        }else{
                            jQuery('#preloader .loader').hide();

                            if(jQuery('.ul_wrapper.toplinks')){
                                jQuery('.shoppingcart').replaceWith(data.sidebar);
                            }

                            jQuery(".shoppingcart .fadelink").bind({
                                mouseenter: function(e) {
                                    jQuery(this).find(".shopping_cart_mini").stop(true, true).fadeIn(300, "linear");
                                },
                                mouseleave: function(e) {
                                    jQuery(this).find(".shopping_cart_mini").stop(true, true).fadeOut(300, "linear");
                                }
                            });
                            if(jQuery('#topline .links')){
                                jQuery('#topline .links').replaceWith(data.toplink);
                            }

                            jQuery('#preloader .inside').html(data.message);
                            jQuery('#preloader .message').fadeIn(300);

                            setTimeout(function(){
                                jQuery('#preloader .message').fadeOut();
                            },1500)
                        }
                    }
                });
            } catch (e) {
            }
            // End of our new ajax code
            this.form.action = oldUrl;
            if (e) {
                throw e;
            }
        }
    }.bind(productAddToCartForm);
    <?php }else { ?>

    productAddToCartForm.submit = function(button, url) {
        if (this.validator.validate()) {
            var form = this.form;
            var oldUrl = form.action;
            if (url) {
                form.action = url;
            }
            var e = null;
            try {
                this.form.submit();
            } catch (e) {
            }
            this.form.action = oldUrl;
            if (e) {
                throw e;
            }
            if (button && button != 'undefined') {
                button.disabled = true;
            }
        }
    }.bind(productAddToCartForm);
    <?php } ?>
    productAddToCartForm.submitLight = function(button, url){
        if(this.validator) {
            var nv = Validation.methods;
            delete Validation.methods['required-entry'];
            delete Validation.methods['validate-one-required'];
            delete Validation.methods['validate-one-required-by-name'];
            // Remove custom datetime validators
            for (var methodName in Validation.methods) {
                if (methodName.match(/^validate-datetime-.*/i)) {
                    delete Validation.methods[methodName];
                }
            }
            if (this.validator.validate()) {
                if (url) {
                    this.form.action = url;
                }
                this.form.submit();
            }
            Object.extend(Validation.methods, nv);
        }
    }.bind(productAddToCartForm);
    <?php if(!Mage::helper('lightboxes')->isActive()):?>
    jQuery("a.video").click(function() {
        jQuery.fancybox({
            'padding'       : 0,
            'autoScale'     : false,
            'transitionIn'  : 'none',
            'transitionOut' : 'none',
            'title'         : this.title,
            'width'     : 680,
            'height'        : 495,
            'href'          : this.href.replace(new RegExp("watch\\?v=", "i"), 'v/'),
            'type'          : 'swf',
            'swf'           : {
                'wmode'     : 'transparent',
                'allowfullscreen'   : 'true'
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
    <?php endif;?>
    //]]>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
When you have products with multiple options the details box ends up way beneath them so that the customer many not even see them. So, just in case anyone else has this issue & wants/needs assistance doing this. In order to move the "Details/Description" box above the add to cart button & keep the add to cart button functioning......

1. Details/Description Box - move the following code to above the last two </div> right before <!--PRODUCT BOX EOF-->:

<?php  $modules_enable=Mage::getStoreConfig('advanced/modules_disable_output');?>
<div class="row">
    <div class="span12">
        <ul class="nav-tabs" id="myTab">
            <li class="active"><a href="#tab1"><?php echo $this->__('Description') ?></a></li>


         <?php if(!$modules_enable['Mage_Review']):?><li><a href="#tab2"><?php echo $this->__('Reviews') ?></a></li><?php endif;?>
                <?php if(!$modules_enable['Mage_Tag']):?><li><a href="#tab3"><?php echo $this->__('Tags') ?></a></li><?php endif;?>
                <?php if ($_customtab && Mage::getStoreConfig('buyshoplayout/product_info/custom_tab')): ?>
                <li><a href="#tab4"><?php if(!empty($_cu`enter code here`stomtabtitle)) echo html_entity_decode($this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($this->getProduct(), $_customtabtitle, 'customtabtitle'));else echo 'Custom tab title' ?></a></li>
                <?php endif;?>
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
                    <?php foreach ($this->getChildGroup('detailed_info', 'getChildHtml') as $alias => $html):?>
                    <div class="box-collateral <?php echo "box-{$alias}"?>">
                        <?php if ($title = $this->getChildData($alias, 'title')):?>
                        <h2><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($title); ?></h2>
                        <?php endif;?>
                        <?php echo $html; ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php endforeach;?>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('reviews') ?>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="tab3">
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_additional_data') ?>
                </div>
                <?php if ($_customtab): ?>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="tab4">
                    <?php echo $this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($this->getProduct(), $_customtab, 'customtab') ?>
                </div>
                <?php endif; ?>


    2. Add to cart button -  move the following code beneath <!--PRODUCT BOX EOF-->  (Each piece of code is located in a separate part of the product box so just look for them & put them together)

    <form action="<?php echo $this->getSubmitUrl($_product) ?>" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form"<?php if($_product->getOptions()): ?> enctype="multipart/form-data"<?php endif; ?>>

    And

    <?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $this->hasOptions()):?>
                        <?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container1', '', true, true) ?>
                        <?php endif;?>
                        <?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $this->hasOptions()):?>
                        <?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container2', '', true, true) ?>
                        <?php endif;?>

    And

    </form>
```